# Noninteger indices for tables

Tags: list-manipulation

Is it bad programming practice to use non-integer values to label data tables? For example,

```
Do[data[dBx, Bz] = Table[{x,f[dBx,Bz]}, {dBx, .1, .5, .05}, {Bz, .4, 1.5, .1}]
```

instead of introducing integer indices for the values of `{dBx,Bz}`.

It works fine most of the time.  But sometimes when I plot the data, *i.e.,*

```
ListDensityplot[Table[{dBx,Bz,data[dBx,Bz]},{dBx, .1, .5, .05}, {Bz, .4, 1.5, .1}]]
```

some values are missing because for some reason Mathematica adds some tiny numerical values to the indices that get called in the plot, so that  `0.1` becomes `0.10000000000002`

Comment: There are many mistakes in your code. Could you post an example where this produces a `ListDensityPlot`?

Comment: There is some terminology confusion here. When one writes `x[.3]` that is not an index into `x` in the same sense an an index of an array. An array or matrix index has to be discrete. Can't be fraction and floating points. In Mathematica that is `x[[index]]` with 2 braces not one. When using one `[i]` , then `i` here is not an index in the same sense as with arrays. it is called a `Down value`, like a hashing value. Also called `indexed` variables sometimes (which can confuse one with normal index), but the `i` in `x[i]` is not an index as normally called  in other languages.

Comment: If the precision of the iterators is causing a problem use exact numbers -- but exact numbers don't have to be integers. For example, `{dBx, .1, .5, .05}` can be written exactly as `{dBx, 1/10, 5/10, 5/100}` or `{dBx, 1/10, 1/2, 1/20}`.

Answer (score 1):

since this has popped up as unanswered, one approach to this if you really *want* to use floating values as "indices" is to save up the "index" values and use them directly as iterators:

```
 dbvals = Table[ dBx , {dBx, .1, .5, .05} ] ;
 bzvals = Table[ Bz , {Bz, .4, 1.5, .1} ] ;
 Do[data[dBx, Bz] = {x, f[dBx, Bz]}, {dBx, dbvals}, {Bz, bzvals}]
 ListDensityPlot[
    Table[{dBx, Bz, data[dBx, Bz]}, {dBx, dbvals}, {Bz, bzvals}]]
```

This will "work" regardless of floating arithmetic issues.